# Check if a function is called with parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Codeigniter has a syntax for url parameter passing for functions inside the controller.

If a function for example:

```
function index($id){
     $this->model->get_user($id);
}
```

Assuming that this function is called without supplying the ID namely called as

```
ProjectName/Controller/index
```

it will return an error as it expects a parameter.
Is there a way to check if a parameter exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not a way to check if one exists per-say as that error happens before the controller has a chance to run code.  ie. before the class method executes.

That said there is a simple workaround for this:  You can supply a default value and check for that for example

```
function index($id = null){
     if( is_null($id) ){
          ///do something - like show a pretty error, or redirect etc...
     }else{
        $this->model->get_user($id);
     }
}
```

This way when no parameter is supplied the ID will be null, this is fairly safe ( when using null ) because you can never supply null as part of the url path even doing this

```
   www.mysite.com/index/null  //or however the url works out in your case
```

Will supply null as a string, because everything in the url comes through as a string.  So `'null'` as a string is not in fact `null` it's just the word null.  If that makes sense.  So given that `null` could never be supplied and only happens if no other value is supplied.

In this case it may be worth casting the input to a int or further checking if it's an improper value.

This could be done several ways:

Casting:

```
  function index($id = null){
     if( is_null($id) ){
          ///do something - like show a pretty error, or redirect etc...
     }else{
        $this->model->get_user((int)$id);
        //cast to int, things that are not INT or string equivalents become 0, which should not find a user as it would look for ID = 0
     }
}
```

By Regx check:

```
function index($id = null){
     if( is_null($id) ){
          ///do something - like show a pretty error, or redirect etc...
    }else if( preg_match('/^[^\d]+$/', $id )){
         // not an int ( contains anything other than a digit )
    }else{
        $this->model->get_user($id);
     }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, this looks brilliant. I will try this and i will inform you on how it will go for me.

Comment: Sure, it was simple thing for me.

Comment: It's also possible to catch these errors using a custom error handler, but that is much more complex and probably not worth the effort.  The only advantage it would have is possible being less maintenance, because it may be possible to set it up once and not have to change the controller methods at all.  here is the PHP function for that, but you would have to use a regular expression on the `$file` to see if it's in the controllers http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Basically that would let you catch all php errors, then with some parsing you could find if it's one you want, and where it came from, and then send it to a custom error page instead of added the above in for each case.  It would be tricky to setup though.

Comment: that's interesting, although due to project time constraints.. i might go for the much simpler work around. Thank you, you really helped me a lot :)